# Transforming Photos to ICAO Standard

Tags: photo-editing

Is there any tool/application that can transform photos that are not in conformity to the ICAO standard to become [ICAO standard](http://miami.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/photo_specifications.xml)?

Comment: ICAO conform images equals biometric images?

Comment: There are a lot of requirements and some of them can be fulfilled (for the moment) only by human. But You can start with correct exposure, colour temperature, focus, lightening.

Comment: Please provide some example images that are not ICAO conformant that you would like to see transformed.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr Yes

Comment: @scottbb Please refer to  [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XhWd4guZ5yH9WfyYuFI5NfhgcWWJbSjB/view?usp=sharing) and  [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aCUwvO3Sj6ODulztHgV1GXyfSXdGk-RD/view?usp=sharing) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

While not specifically stated in the documents I looked at, the implication  is: The photograph is for identification purposes. Any modifications made by photo editing, be it manual or software, invalidates. The guidelines are straight forward, if your picture does not comply, any shop that makes passport pictures can make a compliant image.